# Python openglcontext install fails on MacOS 11.6

Tags: python, macos, opengl

I am trying to get started with PyOpenGL and do some of the tutorials. Using python 3.9.7. I installed PyOpenGL with good results:

```
% pip3 install PyOpenGL PyOpenGL_accelerate
Collecting PyOpenGL
  Downloading PyOpenGL-3.1.5-py3-none-any.whl (2.4 MB)
Collecting PyOpenGL_accelerate
  Downloading PyOpenGL-accelerate-3.1.5.tar.gz (538 kB)
```

I then tried to install OpenGLContext with horrible results. Included here is only one of several ways that it tried to download and failed. Is this package Python 2.7 dependen?

Also, it says "Check the logs for full command output". Where would those logs be?

```
% pip3 install "OpenGLContext-full"
Collecting OpenGLContext-full
  Downloading OpenGLContext-full-3.1.0b1.tar.gz (1.1 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: PyOpenGL>=3.1.0b1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from OpenGLContext-full) (3.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: PyOpenGL-accelerate>=3.1.0b1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from OpenGLContext-full) (3.1.5)
Collecting OpenGLContext>=2.3.0b1
  Downloading OpenGLContext-2.3.0b1.zip (1.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.0 MB 4.0 MB/s            
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/zx/bbkpbk9x48v95vgbwdd7qp_r0000gr/T/pip-install-hn4v657q/openglcontext_3bb9417f4faa4df6aee8c706ca58025f/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/zx/bbkpbk9x48v95vgbwdd7qp_r0000gr/T/pip-install-hn4v657q/openglcontext_3bb9417f4faa4df6aee8c706ca58025f/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/zx/bbkpbk9x48v95vgbwdd7qp_r0000gr/T/pip-pip-egg-info-j0ixugkm
       cwd: /private/var/folders/zx/bbkpbk9x48v95vgbwdd7qp_r0000gr/T/pip-install-hn4v657q/openglcontext_3bb9417f4faa4df6aee8c706ca58025f/
  Complete output (6 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/private/var/folders/zx/bbkpbk9x48v95vgbwdd7qp_r0000gr/T/pip-install-hn4v657q/openglcontext_3bb9417f4faa4df6aee8c706ca58025f/setup.py", line 10
      except ImportError, err:
                        ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/00/8cefe597291c6bfaa102f55a7736c2a176b5dfde48782b8ce534a6cbe06e/OpenGLContext-2.3.0b1.zip#sha256=74cfe788c85674d3b7798e77d055f9bb79c56a4ac6f21ae665944764c8fcd055 (from https://pypi.org/simple/openglcontext/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: OpenGLContext hasn't been updated since 2014. I highly doubt it's compatible with new python versions. Edit: Found a duplicate conforming it.

Comment: So, BDL, that appears to mean that most of the best Python OpenGL tutorials are dead in the water, since they require that package. Do you know of any others that might be worth my looking at? I really just want to get started!!